# Why does the address of l increase by ten when next points to NULL

Tags: c

```
typedef struct Node *List;
struct Node{
    int data;
    List next;
};
List buildList(){
    int n; scanf("%d", &n); 
    List l = (List) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    l->next = NULL; 
    List t = l;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        List q = (List) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        scanf("%d", &(q->data)); q->next = NULL;
        t->next = q; t = t->next;
    }
    return l;
}
```

I am doing some exercise about linked lists with the environment: win10, mingw64. But I found the question just like the title says, why the address of  `l` will add 10 after `l->next = NULL`  . I hope I have given enough information for this question.
[before][image: 1]
[after][image: 2]

Comment: Rather than _the address of `l`_, which would be `&l`, you mean the address in `l`, or the value of `l`, or just `l`.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You initialize `l` to the memory returned by malloc.  Assigning something to `l->next` does not change the the address `l`.

Comment: Your compiler might have optimized the code, and the debugger shows the previous contents of that space that is used for `l`. Look into the generated assembly, or compile without optimization to check this. -- Your source is badly formatted, don't put multiple statements into one line.

Comment: It's a good idea to separate input from the algorithm.  The latter is much easier to test if you write test cases with fixed data instead of having to provide input.  Don't  cast the `void *` returned by `malloc`.

Comment: Those are hexadecimal addresses so the increase `0x10` isn't ten but sixteen. As you have allocated memory for the node, the location of the node has no relation to the location of the previous node. But here, the inference is that `malloc` works with a minimum size of 16 bytes.

Comment: It's confusing that you typedef the pointer to a Node as an unrelated name List, but then in the malloc call you use the struct Node.   I rarely use typedef, but if you do, be consistent.  For example, you could typedef the struct instead of the pointer.  You can use the variable name in sizeof instead of the type.  In this case it would be `sizeof(*l)`.

Comment: Hey guys, I know why this problem arises. I don't know when I add an expression: ```l++``` to  WATCH in VSCode when I debugging, so the ```l``` will add 0x10 (thanks for Weather Vane point out the problem) for each time call...  Actually, it's first for me to know this thing. But I am really sorry for my stupidity, and I sincerely thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the variable `List l = (List) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));` and make no further changes to it.  `l->next = NULL` changes the the pointer `l->next` but it does not change `l`.

Observe the following minimal program that fails to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node *List;
struct Node{
    int data;
    List next;
};

int main() {
    List l = (List) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    printf("before: %p\n", l);
    l->next = NULL;
    printf("after:  %p\n", l);
    return 0;
}
```

and on my machine this run prints:

```
before: 0x556e021392a0
after:  0x556e021392a0
```

Comment: As sensible as your assertion _it does not change `l`_ sounds, it does not address the behavior which is visible in the debugger screenshots, so it doesn't answer the question;  
the busybee's comment is presumably the answer.

Comment: Op could run my program through debugger and it and output agrees.  We know nothing about the debugger.  We don't know if the two screen dumps are indeed after running a single step.

Comment: I can't comprehend your sentence _Op could run my program through debugger and it and output agrees._

Comment: Yeah, I screwed up edit under the 5 min time pressure.  Op asked in title "Why does the address of l increase" and I said it does not, and provided a minimal program that proves that.   Op is not asking why the debugger is showing incorrect information.  @thebusybee or others are welcome to provide a different answer, of course, and op can tell us by accepting the best answer. Evidence is two screenshots.  It's also possible that the data is incorrect (say, from two different runs).  We only have a snippet of code so we can't reproduce it.

Comment: Thank for your answer, actually, the reason is that I add an expression: ```l++``` to WATCH in VSCode.... I'm sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: We all make mistakes and learn from them.  If you don't know, it increases by sizeof(struct Node) = 0x10 = 16 as it's `List` is a `struct Node *`.  If it was a char * it would increase by 1.  Accept answer if that helped you, later you also have the options of voting up on helpful answers.